# How to colour box plot lines of each unique value of data?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a box plot of male and female lifespan, and data points of each sex are connected with a line according to the species. 
My question is, how I could assign each species a unique colour of line? As my data set is very large, it would be great if I could assign x number of random colours to each species automatically. 
Also for some reason, my x axis labels will not appear as I'd like. I would like the axis to be labelled "Sex" with Male and then Female labels for each box plot.

Using this data:

```
MaleFemale.max.longevity    Sex Binomial
195 Male    Agouti_paca
192 Female  Agouti_paca
196 Male    Alopex_lagopus
126 Female  Alopex_lagopus
240 Male    Amblonyx_cinereus
276 Female  Amblonyx_cinereus
254 Male    Aotus_azarai
174 Female  Aotus_azarai
310 Male    Arctictis_binturong
324 Female  Arctictis_binturong
430 Male    Cacajao_calvus
276 Female  Cacajao_calvus
314 Male    Callicebus_moloch
244 Female  Callicebus_moloch
223 Male    Callithrix_pygmaea
181 Female  Callithrix_pygmaea
164 Male    Canis_adustus
130 Female  Canis_adustus
```

And this code (kindly taken from another question on this website - very helpful):

```
Longevity <- log10(News$MaleFemale.max.longevity)
# Graph plots 
r <- ggplot(News, aes(x = Sex, y = Longevity, fill = Sex)) + 
scale_x_discrete(c(labels = unique("Female","Male"), each = 2))
r <- r + geom_boxplot(color="grey40", outlier.alpha=0.0) 
r <- r + stat_summary(fun.y=mean,geom="point",pch="-",color="white",size=8,
position = position_dodge(width=0.75))
r <- r + geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.6, aes(group=Sex), data=News, position =
position_dodge(width=0.75))
r <- r + geom_line(aes(group = Binomial), alpha = 0.6, colour = "black", data
= News)  
r <- r + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#969696","#74c476"))
r <- r + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), 
axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
legend.position = "none")
r
```

This is what I've been able to produce so far:

[image]

Comment: To lable x-axis: `+ xlab("Sex")`

Comment: To label line automatically, you need to include `color` inside `aes` i.e: `geom_line(aes(group = Binomial, color = Binomial))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that no the x-label doesn't appear is because you write `axis.title.x = element_blank()`. This effectively removes the label. In order to get colored lines, you should put `aes(group = Binomial, color = Binomial)` and remove `colour = 'black'`. However, with this many colors you won't be able to see the differences. Anyway, below is a slightly cleaned-up version of your code with the suggested edits.

```
# Graph plots 
r <- ggplot(News, aes(x = Sex, y = log10(MaleFemale.max.longevity), fill = Sex)) + 
  geom_boxplot(color="grey40", outlier.alpha=0.0) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", pch="-", color="white", size=8,
               position = position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  geom_point(size=2, alpha=0.6, aes(group=Sex),
             position = position_dodge(width=0.75)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Binomial, group = Binomial), alpha = 0.6)  +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#969696","#74c476")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(colour = 'black'), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = "none") +
  labs(y = 'Longevity')
print(r)
```

Comment: Thanks shadow - your version of the script is great. As you said, the colours aren't very helpful in visualising the relationship. Is there a way to change the size of the x and y axis so the lines are a bit more spread out?